# "Extreme" CPU usage on Drupal site, account disabled as a result

Tags: performance, caching, drupal, drupal-7, cpu

I suddenly got a spike in CPU usage on shared hosting and my website has been taken offline for the past 48 hours. I have already tried the following, and it did not help (or only a bit):

- Updated Drupal 7 and all modules to the latest version
- activated CloudFlare
- disabled any unused modules

Caching was already on (min cache lifetime: none; expiration cached pages: 1 hour; bandwidth optimization: all options checked). I had no problems before, and visitor numbers have remained fairly constant at 1500-2000 a day. Could it be hacked? Spam? The logs only show lots of Google bot "access denied" activity, but somehow doubt that can take the site down.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What has this to do with programming?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost)** module, this will help you improve the performance by creating HTML files.

> Boost provides static page caching for Drupal enabling a very
>   significant performance and scalability boost for sites that receive
>   mostly anonymous traffic. For shared hosting this is your best option
>   in terms of improving performance. On dedicated servers, you may want
>   to consider Varnish instead.
>
> Apache is fully supported, with Nginx, Lighttpd and IIS 7
>   semi-supported. Boost will cache & gzip compress html, xml, ajax, css,
>   & javascript. Boosts cache expiration logic is very advanced; it's
>   fairly simple to have different cache lifetimes for different parts of
>   your site. The built in crawler makes sure expired content is quickly
>   regenerated for fast page loading.